# Reducing code while posting inputs to database?

Tags: php, sql, database

I have several inputs that require essentially the same line of code, just altered for different places in the database (as determined by columnA). Is there any way to create a simple loop to minimize the amount of manual code I have to use?

```
    Step One: Get variables
      $w1001a = $_POST['w1001a'];   
      $w1001b = $_POST['w1001b'];
      ....
      $w1025b = $_POST['w1025b'];

    Step Two: Update database
      mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE table SET content = '$w1001a' WHERE columnA='w1001a'");   
      mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE table SET content = '$w1001b' WHERE columnA='w1001b'");
      ....
      mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE table SET content = '$w1025b' WHERE columnA='w1025b'");
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just hint:

```
for ($i=1; $i<=25; $i++)
    for ($j='a'; $j<='b'; $j++) {
        $k = 'w10'.str_pad($i, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT).$j;
        mysqli_query($conn, 'UPDATE table SET content=\''.$_POST[$k].'\' WHERE columnA=\''.$k.'\'');
    }
```

NOTE: you need to use parametrized queries or at least escape strings to avoid SQL injections